# Linux - Recover a deleted Java file

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, ubuntu-14.04, file-recovery

Today I was coding in Android Studio when suddenly the computer ran out of battery and it shut down, and when I restarted the computer, I found the Java file empty.

How can I do to recover this file? I have tried R-Linux, Scalpel... and without any luck.

Thank you.

(I'm using Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Was the file ever saved to disk before the computer shut down? There's nothing you can do if it never touched the disk.

Comment: Yes, it was saved